# Twitter bootstrap affixed panel's width shrinks when I scroll down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My code looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-8"> ... </div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="side-panel" class="panel panel-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="10">
        PANEL'S WIDTH SHRINKS WHEN I SCROLL DOWN :(
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to implement side-affixed bootstrap panel. But when I scroll down the page, it is affixed on top as I wanted but it's width shrinks to about half.

I also tried `position: fixed;` style attribute but it ended up with identical shrinkage.

What is the actual problem in here and is there any workaround for this weird behavior?

Comment: can u create a plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly define the `width` or `min-width` of `side-panel` to keep it from "shrinking". The attribute `data-spy="affix"` is doing exactly what you did - setting `position: fixed` on the panel. When position is fixed the panel will "shrink" down to the size of whatever content is inside it.